# ROC in Multiclass kNN

Tags: r, r-caret, roc

Im trying to run some ROC analysis on a multiclass knn model and dataset

so far i have this code for the kNN model. It works well.
`X_train_new` is a dataset with 131 numeric variables (columns) and 7210 observations.
`Y_train` is the outcome variable which i have as factor. its a dataset with only 1 column (activity) and 7210 observations (there are 6 possible factors)

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method  = "cv",
                     number  = 10)

model2 <-    train(X_train_new,
                   Y_train$activity,
                   method     = "knn",
                   tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 5),
                   trControl  = ctrl,
                   metric     = "Accuracy"
)
```

`X_test_new` is a dataset with 131 numeric variables (columns) and 3089 observations.
`Y_test` is the outcome variable which i have as factor. its a dataset with only 1 column and 3089 observations (there are 6 possible factors)

I run the predict function

```
knnPredict_test <- predict(model2 , newdata = X_test_new )
```

I would like to do some ROC analysis on each class vs all. Im trying

```
a = multiclass.roc ( Y_test$activity, knnPredict_test )
```

`knnPredict_test` is a vector with predicted classes:

```
knnPredict_test <- predict(model2 ,newdata = X_test_new )
> length(knnPredict_test)
[1] 3089
> glimpse(knnPredict_test)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "laying","sitting",..: 2 1 5 1 3 2 4 5 3 2 ...
```

This is the error im getting

```
Error in roc.default(response, predictor, levels = X, percent = percent,  :   
Predictor must be numeric or ordered.
```

Comment: The error message seems rather emphatic and informative. It also seems perfectly understandable to my eyes. If you believe otherwise, then please do describe in much greater detail than you have attempted so far exactly how one would construct an ROC curve with an unordered predictor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ROC, you need a numeric prediction. However, by default `predict` will give you the predicted classes. Use `type = "prob"`.

Here is a reproducable example which has the same error.

```
library(caret)

knnFit <- train(
  Species ~ .,
  data = iris,
  method = "knn"
)

predictions_bad <- predict(knnFit)

pROC::multiclass.roc(iris$Species, predictions_bad)
#> Error in roc.default(response, predictor, levels = X, percent = percent,  : 
#>   Predictor must be numeric or ordered.
```

Using `type = "prob"` fixes the error.

```
predictions_good <- predict(knnFit, type = "prob")

pROC::multiclass.roc(iris$Species, predictions_good)
#> Call:
#> multiclass.roc.default(response = iris$Species, predictor = predictions_good)
#> 
#> Data: multivariate predictor predictions_good with 3 levels of iris$Species: setosa, versicolor, virginica.
#> Multi-class area under the curve: 0.9981
```

Comment: dont i need to add the test data to the predict function?
`knnPredict_test_1 <- predict(model2, newdata = X_test_new, type = "prob")`

Comment: Yes. My example is simplified.